# Как добавить maven-репозиторий jitpack.io в build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

Мне нужно добавить вот этот кусок для работы библиотеки, но нигде не могу найти информацию куда его ставить, пришлите пожалуйста скриншот или напиши конкретно куда его ставить и под чем. Зачем мне это нужно?
Да вот с git hub хочу использовать эту оповещалку : https://github.com/Tapadoo/Alerter. Когда я открыл проект Tapadoo,то увидел 4 gradle файла, в то время как у меня их только 3 и нету нигде allprojects.
[image: settings.gradle]

Кусок:

```
allprojects {
 repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
 }
}
```

Comment: Если у вас в проекте есть файл `settings.gradle`, то приложите его содержимое в вопрос.

Comment: У вас на скрине как раз нужная строка подсвечена, только не весь блок туда вписать нужно, а только строку `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }`

Comment: то есть у меня после этого будет работать библиотека?

Comment: Я не знаю будет ли она работать - я ей не пользовался. Это добавит репозиторий jitpack и грэдл будет искать в нём зависимости, в том числе нужную вам библиотеку. Именно для этого и нужен этот кусок кода.